# Optparser-print Usage Help when no argument is given

Tags: python

What I am doing now is to simply check for args length, if it is 0, tell user to type -h.

Is there a better way to do this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear from your question whether you are using the (deprecated) [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html) module or its replacement, the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) module. Assuming the latter, then as long as you have at least one positional argument your script will print out a usage message if no arguments (or insufficient arguments) are supplied.

Here's an example script:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A dummy program")
parser.add_argument('positional', nargs="+", help="A positional argument")
parser.add_argument('--optional', help="An optional argument")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

If I run this with no arguments, I get this result:

```
usage: script.py [-h] [--optional OPTIONAL] positional [positional ...]
script.py: error: too few arguments
```

Comment: The optparse module was designed around the concept of command line _options_ and therefore doesn't give you much help with positional or required arguments (see the documentation linked to in divad12's answer - and my own). The appropriate way to check for positional arguments is to check the args returned by `optparse.parseargs()` which seems to be what you're already doing.

Answer (score 19):

You can do it with optparse just fine.  You don't need to use argparse.

```
if options.foo is None: # where foo is obviously your required option
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax errors and 1 for all other kind of errors. Thus this exit code looks convenient.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for @forkchop for the hint parser.print_help() !!!

then I think it could be like this?

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
...
options, remainder = parser.parse_args()
if len(sys.argv[1:]) == 0:
    print "no argument given!"
    parser.print_help()
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I have handled this approach before:

```
import optparse
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
...
if len(sys.argv) == 1: # if only 1 argument, it's the script name
    parser.print_help()
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html

It should do what users normally expect from command line apps -- when `-h` flag is given, it will show usage help.

Comment: I just want to make my tool a bit more flexible for people who might not be familiar with command line tools.